# Pywin32not recognized in my computer

Tags: python, excel, download, pywin32, win32com

I downloaded pywin32 for my computer. I inputted

```
import win32com.client
x1 = win32.Dispatch("Excel.Application)"
```

and I get an error saying that win32 is not defined. Is it because I installed it wrong? If so can you give me advice as to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the `Dispatch` function is in the `win32com.client` module, so you would need to do:

```
x1 = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
```

See the [Quick Start to Client side COM and Python](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/html/com/win32com/HTML/QuickStartClientCom.html) documentation for further explanation and examples.

Answer (score 0):

You imported `win32com.client`, but you're trying to call the `Dispatch` method/class from `win32`. You need to `import win32` first.

Comment: it says I have no module named win32. Does it not come in pywin32?

Comment: There is no win32 in pywin32. Rather it is a typo it should be `win32com.Dispatch`